# FragmentPagerAdapter: Change title of visible fragment

Tags: android, fragment, fragmentpageradapter

In my forecast app i implement a fragment for each day.

The architecture is :
FragmentActivity << PagerTabStrip+ViewPager << FragmentPagerAdapter

All work fine.
My need is to display the fragment title depending on its visibility in this way:

01/10/16 | 02 october 2016 | 03/10/16

My first idea is to do it in the FragmentPagerAdapter in:

```
public void set_current_position(int i)
{
    mCurrent_position = i;
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position)
{
    String strDT = null;
    boolean isTop = (position == mCurrent_position);
    Fragment fragment = (Fragment) getItem(position);
    Bundle data = fragment.getArguments();
    long ts = data.getLong(keyDate);
    Date date = new Date(ts);

    if (isTop)
        strDT = FullDateFormat(date);
    else
        strDT = ShortDateFormat(date);

    return strDT;
}
```

The result is not constant; some time it work nice but some times not.
I think that the `set_current_position` is executed randomly 'before or after' `getPageTitle`.

Did you have any idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting the [OnTabSelectedListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.ViewPagerOnTabSelectedListener.html) to your TabLayout.

```
tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        // do your stuff

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

    }
});
```

Comment: The tableLayout can resolve my issue, but I can't display only 3 tabs (of 7).

Comment: or this http://blog.dandyer.co.uk/2011/04/18/scrolling-tabs-in-android/

Comment: The both solutions displays all the 7 tabs. For now I will let it as is, waiting for free time to investigate. Many thanks for your help